# How to do hotfixes with GitHub Pull Requests

Tags: github, git-flow

Caveat: I am fairly new to both git and GitHub.

So, in my current setup, my team uses git flow Hotfixes (usually started and finished by a graphical tool such as GitKraken or IntelliJ) to make changes that have to be merged into two branches and pushed upstream in both. So for example the flow would be:

1. Pull latest from master
2. Start hotfix
3. Commit changes
4. Merge hotfix branch into both master and develop and push both upstream

We're now looking at moving our code into GitHub and would like to start using Pull Requests, for a couple of reasons:

- CI hooks to run tests and stuff
- a place to put code-specific comments not directly related to the underlying "issue"
- avoiding the need for everyone to constantly be pulling the latest master/develop to their local machine so that they can merge changes

But in the case of Hotfixes, I'm not sure what to do because I'm merging into two branches but it really is one "action" so manually creating two pull requests seems weird, particularly since step 4) in our current flow is a single click.

Is there a smart way of handling this? My ideal case would be that pushing the Merge button on the Pull Request would just merge into both, but that doesn't seem to be an available option.

Comment: similar question http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187723/code-review-with-git-flow-and-github

Comment: @Robbie thanks, I'll review those as well.

Comment: Nowadays you can automate a lot using github actions. There are some premade gitflow actions available, but I haven't tested any of them

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As you mentioned, a Pull Request has only **one** target branch, so you won't be able to push the hotfix to both `master` and `develop` by merging one Pull Request.

I'm also surprised you mention your step #4 - merging the hotfix branch to both `master` and `develop` and push upstream - is one action. While there's a high chance the merge from `hotfix` to `master` won't run into merge conflicts, I can't say the same for the merge from `hotfix` to `develop` since it could have been worked on since the last deployment to production.

My recommendation would then be the following:

- Create one PR from `hotfix` to `master` and have someone review it to validate the fix
- Once it's merged into `master`, create another PR from `hotfix` to `develop` and see if you run into merge conflicts

  - If that's the case, resolve the merge conflicts so the PR ends up in a state to be merged, and have someone review the PR
  - If there's no merge conflicts, then have someone review the PR

---

An alternative solution, if you really want to go down the automated path, would be to leverage both GitHub webhooks and API.

The webhook would allow you to be [notified when a PR is merged](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestevent). You could inspect the payload to make sure that the base branch starts with `hotfix/` and the target branch is `master`. You could then react to that event by using the API to [create a new PR](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request) from the same `hotfix` branch to `develop`.

It will involve some development, and the effort might not be worth since creating a PR via the UI is still quite easy and quick.

Comment: This is a very nice approach, thanks for explaining. But is it safe if one of the two PRs was merged using squashing or rebasing? Could this lead to conflicts when develop is merged into master again?

Comment: The benefit of the automatic approach is you cannot forget to merge back to master

Comment: I have done the same, first a PR to master and then another PR to develop

Comment: What about "behind | ahead" commits? This approach will make your master/main branch end up with commits that you never gonna have in your develop brach. That's ok?

Comment: good point @gsubiran. I'm wondering about the same thing.

Comment: @tmw I ended up doing the following. Developers make PR to develop from your particular branches. When done an admin creates a release branch with the new version. If there is something to fix, developers will create a brach from this release and fix it, then PR back to this release. Here is the important part, when all is ok, an admin with policies to bypass PR creation must merge the release branch to master and develop. This makes no extra commit for PRs so branches are clean and behind | ahead make sense again. I don't know if is a good practice to bypass policies but I is the way I found.

Comment: @tmw I did another find in this way. "Rebase and fast-forward: Creates a linear history by replaying the source branch commits onto the target without a merge commit". I think the way we should PR to master is in this way to avoid an extra merge commit. I didn't tried yet but make a lot of sense for me.

Comment: thanks @gsubiran! here's another approach, using gitflow approach; https://git-flow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hotfix.html